# GROUP BY and ORDER BY in UNION

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT category, description, price, date_added, datetime_created
FROM vc_expense
WHERE trip_id=? AND description LIKE ?
GROUP BY description, price    

UNION SELECT category, description, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM vc_expense_default
WHERE description LIKE ?    

ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN description LIKE ? AND price THEN 1
  WHEN price THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END, date_added DESC, datetime_created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

My problem is that when I GROUP the description+price on row #4, it doesn't take into account that I want the most recent results:

```
date_added DESC, datetime_created DESC
```

Is there a way to use ORDER BY after row #4 so I can get the newest items only, it doesn't seem to work because of the UNION

Thanks!

Edit:
   The UNION was irrelevant, I just had put it inside parantheses, and get the latest items only from each group, like this:

```
SELECT e1.category, e1.description, e1.price, e1.date_added, e1.datetime_created
FROM vc_expense e1
LEFT JOIN vc_expense e2 ON (
    e1.description=e2.description AND
    e1.price=e2.price AND
    e1.date_added < e2.date_added
)
WHERE e2.id IS NULL AND e1.trip_id = ? AND e1.description LIKE ?
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

> Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about
>   the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION
>   by default produces an unordered set of rows

and here's what you need:

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10) UNION (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: Yup, you're right! The UNION was actually irrelevant. Check the edit to see the working code, thanks!